# Can't sort items by createdAt

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/y66RgYMAgSo?t=1996) for an E-commerce website and applying the Sort functionality.

I've compared my code to the source code and I don't think there's difference in the method that the tutorial uses so I'm a little confused right now.

Here is the instructor's [source code](https://github.com/safak/youtube/blob/mern-ecommerce-app/client/src/components/Products.jsx)

#### Problem Description:

- Sorting the products by the `price` field ascending & descending works. But somehow, it *cannot* sort the `latest` and `oldest` products by the `createdAt` field.
- If I do a `console.log(a.createdAt - b.createdAt)`, it would return `NaN`.

[image]

- In MongoDB, all items have both the `createdAt` and `price` fields.

[image]

- If I do console log on `a.createdAt` or `b.createdAt`, it returns the `createdAt` result as in the item.

[image]

- If I console.log(filteredProducts), it returns all 5 objects that contains the same 5 items.

[image]

-> **Question**: How would we fix this problem or is there a better way to sort items based on created date in this case?

---

### Below is my code:

**Product Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String, 
      required: true, 
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    img: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    categories: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    size: {
      type: Array,
    },
    color: {
      type: Array,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    inStock: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  }, 
  { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema)
```

**Products.js**

```
const Products = ({ category, filters, sort }) => {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    category && setFilteredProducts(
      products.filter(item => 
        Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => 
          item[key].includes(value)
        )
      )
    )
  }, [category, filters, products])

  // Sorting:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Sort by latest date:
    if (sort === "latest") {
      setFilteredProducts(prev =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => 
          a.createdAt - b.createdAt
          // console.log(a.createdAt - b.createdAt) -> This returns "NaN"
        )
      )
    } else if (sort === "asc") {
      setFilteredProducts(prev =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
      )
    } else if (sort === "desc") {
      setFilteredProducts(prev =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
      )
    } else {
      // Sort by oldest date:
      setFilteredProducts(prev =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt)
      )
    }
  }, [sort])

  return (
    <Container>
      <Title>Popular In Store</Title>
      <ProductsWrapper>
        {filteredProducts.map(item => (
        <Product key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
      </ProductsWrapper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm either missing it or misunderstanding the code I don't see where any object has a `createdAt` property. `undefined - undefined` would certainly yield a `NaN` value. Can you update your question to include all relevant details, like the value of `filteredProducts` that you are trying to sort?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I've updated the screenshots and value of `filteredProducts`. It's interesting that all items have the `createdAt` field but cannot do a sort functionality. Does this has to relate with performing a minus on a string (`createdAt`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createdAt` property is a non-number-like string, so attempting arithmetic operations on them will result in `NaN`.

```js
console.log("2022-04-03T07:55:18.556Z" - "2022-04-12T07:55:18.556Z"); // NaN
```

Use [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare string values in a sort comparator.

```js
console.log("2022-04-03T07:55:18.556Z".localeCompare("2022-04-12T07:55:18.556Z")); // -1
```

Example:

```
// Sorting:
useEffect(() => {
  // Sort by latest date:
  if (sort === "latest") {
    setFilteredProducts(prev =>
      [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.localeCompare(b.createdAt)
    ))
  } else if (sort === "asc") {
    setFilteredProducts(prev =>
      [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
    )
  } else if (sort === "desc") {
    setFilteredProducts(prev =>
      [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
    )
  } else {
    // Sort by oldest date:
    setFilteredProducts(prev =>
      [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt))
    )
  }
}, [sort]);
```

Note this only works when date strings use units in decreasing order of unit size, i.e. year, then month, then day, etc... So ensure your dates conform to this. If this is not practical then you'll need to resort to processing the date strings into DateTime objects and using other methods of comparison.

```js
console.log(new Date("2022-04-03T07:55:18.556Z") - new Date("2022-04-12T07:55:18.556Z")); // -777600000
```